# Can't get mssql_connect to work properly

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect to a specific local server using mssql_connect method but not having any luck.

Any Ideas?

```
mssql_connect('10.12.179.66:1433\ONE_ROOF_PROD', 'username', 'password');
```

Comment: Want to elaborate on "not having any luck"?  Is it returning FALSE?  What does [`mssql_get_last_message`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php) return afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Let php tell you more about the cause of the error.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$link = mssql_connect('10.12.179.66:1433\ONE_ROOF_PROD', $uid, $pass);
if ( !$link ) {
  if ( function_exists('error_get_last') ) {
    var_dump(error_get_last());
  }
  die('connection failed');
}
```

In case you are using windows you might also be interested in the [sqlsrv extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296152%28SQL.90%29.aspx).